# How to set up classes

Tags: class

i am an engineering student enrolled in computer programming trying to understand a practice assignment for an upcoming lab and was wondering if someone could help me with this step of my program, Step: using The init method for the class takes the first formal parameter self and a list of [x, y] pairs v and stores the list as a class instance variable

Comment: There's a lot missing from your question *(including what language you are using, for starters.)*  The step is also not obviously an instruction: "using the X something does Y" suggests something that has already been written, whereas "using the X, make something do Y" is asking you to write code.  For this to be answerable, you will have to edit it to show what code setup you have...and make it clear if writing this `Init` method is your actual task.  Then add a tag for the language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Python, but next time you post a question, make sure you specify that and tag your question as such.  You are looking for something like the following code:

```
class MyClassName(object):
    def __init__(self, pairs):
        self.pairs = pairs
```

Let's look at this line by line:

```
class MyClassName(object):
```

The first line declares a class called `MyClassName`.  It *extends* object, which is not super important to understand right now, but is basically saying that MyClassName is a particular type of object.

```
    def __init__(self, pairs):
```

The second line creates a function called `__init__` which will be called when you *instantiate* an object of type MyClassName.  This line also declares what parameters it takes.  It sounds like you already know that the first argument has to be `self`, and the second parameter, `pairs`, is the list of [x,y] pairs.  In python, we don't need to specify what *type* these parameters are, so we need only to name them (Some languages would require us to specify that `pairs` is going to be a list of pairs).

```
        self.pairs = pairs
```

Now all we have to do is set the instance variable.  Inside a class, `self` refers to this particular *instance* of the object.  In other words, every time we create a variable of type MyClassName, the `self` keyword will refer to that particular instance of the object, rather than to *all* instances of MyClassName.  So in this case, `self.pairs` refers to the variable `pairs` in this particular instance of MyClassName. On the other hand, `pairs` simply refers to the argument passed into the function `__init__`.

So, to put all this together, we have defined a class called MyClassName, then defined the `__init__` function, and in it, we set the instance variable `self.pairs`  to be equal to the `pairs` variable passed into `__init__`.

Last, I'll give a quick example of how to instantiate MyClassName:

```
my_list = [(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16)]
my_instance = MyClassName(my_list)
```

Good luck!

[Edit] Also, I agree with the first comment on your question.  You need to be more clear and verbose in exactly what you are trying to accomplish and not leave it up to guess work.  In this case, I think I could tell what you were trying to do, but it may not always be clear.

Comment: thank you Guys so Much, this really helped on my lab! also thanks for the advice in the future I will be sure to post my questions more concisely and with greater clarity. Once again, thanks

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer answered your question, would you mind marking it as the correct answer (by clicking the checkmark to its left?)